# How to add unique class to Wordpress menu anchor?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have this `function`:

```
function my_walker_nav_menu_start_el($item_output, $item, $depth, $args) {
    // you can put your if statements in here (use item, depth and args in conditions)
    $item_output = preg_replace('/<a /', '<a class="your-class" ', $item_output, 1);
    return $item_output;
}
add_filter('walker_nav_menu_start_el', 'my_walker_nav_menu_start_el', 10, 4);
```

Which is working fine, because it is setting a class on all my `anchors` in the menu. The problem is: it's setting the same class on all anchors. I want different classes per anchor. Is that possible? If so, how can I do this?

Edit --> I want to have it like this:

```
<li><a class="icon-bird"></a></li>
<li><a class="icon-book"></a></li>
<li><a class="icon-red"></a></li>
```

Comment: If all your classes are to be unique, use the `id` attribute instead: `<li><a id="icon-bird"></a></li>`

Comment: I am using icon-fonts, so it has to be a class.... If I add a particular class, it adds an icon before the anchor, that's why I am using classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `$item` contains your values (bird, book, red, etc):

```
function my_walker_nav_menu_start_el($item_output, $item, $depth, $args) {
    $item_output = preg_replace('/<a /', '<a class="item-' . $item . '"', $item_output, 1);
    return $item_output;
}
add_filter('walker_nav_menu_start_el', 'my_walker_nav_menu_start_el', 10, 4);
```

Comment: Thanks, but doesn't this add the same class on all of those anchors? Where do I select the second and third anchor to put a different class to?

Comment: To me it looks like `my_walker_nav_menu_start_el` is called for every item in a collection that's external to the code you've supplied. The function itself doesn't create all your menu items at once, but instead creates one per invocation.

Comment: That's true... But how can we make that happen? Can you help me with that? This is the only thing I have.

Answer (score 0):

I used above code and make some changes and it's work for me , you can try with the below steps:

you can follow the below Steps :

**Step 1 :** In the wp-admin, go to Appearance -> Menus,put the class on the menu item here "CSS Classes (optional)". *If you can't see the "CSS Classes (optional)" in the menu item, then there is "Screen Option" in the right top of the screen and there are the options "CSS Class" under "Show advanced menu properties"*.

**Step 2:** Under your them folder/function.php add below code :

```
 function my_walker_nav_menu_start_el($item_output, $item, $depth, $args) {
    $class= $item->classes['0'];
    $item_output = preg_replace('/<a /', '<a class="'.$class.'"', $item_output, 1);
    return $item_output;
 }
add_filter('walker_nav_menu_start_el', 'my_walker_nav_menu_start_el', 10, 4);
```

Hope above code works for you , let me know if still it doesn't work.