# how to add a custom class to anchor of wordpress navigation menu wp_nav_menu()?

Tags: wordpress

How to add custom class to anchor  Tag of wordpress navigation menu?
I want to add a class to anchor Tag  of wordpress navigation menu here is the code.

```
<ul class="nav">
 <li class="liTop"> <a class="nonblock nontext anim_swing clearfix" href="#home">Home</a> </li>
 <li class="liTop"> <a class="nonblock nontext anim_swing clearfix" href="#about">About</a> </li>
 <li class="liTop"> <a class="nonblock nontext anim_swing clearfix" href="#contact">Contact</a></li> 
</ul>
```

Comment: you can check with the link followed : http://stackoverflow.com/a/29335629/4041670

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add class using jquery...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.nonblock').addClass('your_class_name');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use jquery to solve this problem.

```
$(documrnt).ready(function(){
  $('.nav').find('li').addClass('liTop');
  $('.lilop').find('a').addClass('nonblock nontext anim_swing clearfix');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Guys thanks for your replies but I found my solution. here is the trick.
Paste the following code in functions.php

```
function add_menuclass($ulclass) {
return preg_replace('/rel="nonblock nontext anim_swing clearfix"/', 'class="nonblock nontext anim_swing clearfix"', $ulclass, -1);
}
add_filter('wp_nav_menu','add_menuclass');
```

On the top where is says Screen Options, make sure you have "Link Relationship (XFN)" checked. It will add that field to your custom menu item. Type "your_class" into the field and save your menu.

The function looks for the call to the navigation menu, then finds wherever you have a rel="other_class" and replaces it with a class="your_class". You can replace your_class with whatever class you need to add to your menu items.

Answer (score 0):

```
   /* Add following code in your functions.php */

   function add_class_to_all_menu_anchors( $atts ) {
       $atts['class'] = 'your_custom_class';

       return $atts;
    }
    add_filter( 'nav_menu_link_attributes', 'add_class_to_all_menu_anchors', 10 );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by adding additional arugement in wp_nav_menu and set filter **nav_menu_link_attributes**

Example of adding additional arugment in wp_nav_menu

```
wp_nav_menu(array('menu' => 'Main Navigation', 'menu_id' => '', 'menu_class'=> 'navbar-nav mb-2 mb-lg-0', 'container' => '', 'add_class_on_a' => 'nav-link text-white' ));
```

Next, add filter in theme functions.php file

```
add_filter( 'nav_menu_link_attributes', 'nav_menu_add_class', 10, 3 );

function nav_menu_add_class( $atts, $item, $args ) {
    if(isset($args->add_class_on_a)) {
    $atts['class'] = $args->add_class_on_a;
    }
    return $atts;
}
```